# WP load scripts if template has shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, styles, shortcode

I have a plugin, it has many css theme files. Of course I do not want to load all of them, only one. It depends on config. For post I use **has_shortcode** function, but how todo the same thing with template that use **do_shortcode** function.

**Note:**

I found a good solution, I use

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'init', $plugin_public, 'register_scripts');
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_footer', $plugin_public, 'print_scripts');
```

Inside shortcode handle I set a global var to **true**

```
global $imagelink_plugin_shortcode_used;
$imagelink_plugin_shortcode_used = true;
```

The function **print_scripts** add my scripts if my global var is **true**

```
public function print_scripts() {
   global $imagelink_plugin_shortcode_used;

   if ( ! $imagelink_plugin_shortcode_used )
       return;

   wp_print_scripts($this->plugin_name . '-imagelinks');
}
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: can you please provide more information on which plugin you are using and  make it more clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: If it is a plugin you wrote you can enqueue the script in the shortcode function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using has_shortcode function, what you can do is register and enqueue those files when that shortcode is rendered.

First, register your css files with `wp_register_script`. Make sure to hook this into `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Now, inside your shortcode function, enqueue the files.

`wp_enqueue_style('theme-css')`

Using this way you can use the shortcode anywhere you want and the script is loaded only when shortcode is present on the page whether it is on content or template.

Comment: This will always load your script into the footer, regardles of the in_footer variable. What if we need to hook a script into the header?